# Go to element position based on given Input number

Tags: linux

I have a data in file and need to extract particular data element based on input position number.

Example: Data in file.txt look like:

```
N4*WALTER*WHITE~
```

Input Command:

```
N4*1*
```

look for segment N4 and extract data from position 1

Expected Output:

```
WALTER
```

Input Command:

```
N4*2*
```

look for segment N4 and extract data from position 2

Expected Output:

```
WHITE
```

I know how to extract data segments

grep -P -o '(?<=N4[ * ]).*?(?=~)'

but not sure how to identify the element position (1,2,3) based on input.

Sometimes the data in file.txt look like:

```
~N4*WALTER*WHITE~DMG*D8*19630625~N4*CORA*PA*15108~PER*IR*JESSI*N4*PINK*2838829~
```

So for `N4*1*` Input the output should be

```
WALTER
CORA
```

Note: N4, DMG are the segment identifiers always end with ~

Comment: `look for segment N4` - what does that mean? What segments are there? A "segment N4" is a line starting with `N4*` ? What happened with `~` on the end of line? Why `N4*2*` didn't return `WHITE~`? So the command is actually `grep` for a line starting with a string and `cut` the part of the string? Any reason to use a lookaround `(?<=N4[ * ])` and not just `^N4`? `how to identify the element position (1,2,3)` - just `cut` it. Ex. `cut -d'*' -f3` - will get the 3rd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want `awk` as the tool since you will be matching part of the record and then outputting a certain field based on the number contained in the input.

For example, given your record stored in the file `file`:

```
$ cat file
N4*WALTER*WHITE~
```

You want a way to take user input (say `input='N4*1*'`) and locate the record that begins with `N4` and then output the 1st field following `N4` (the 2nd field from `awk`s standpoint).

One way to do this is take the user input variable `input` and split it into an array in the `BEGIN{...}` section of the `awk` command, and then increment the number in `a[2]` so it corresponds to the wanted `awk` field-number, e.g.

```
input='N4*1*'
...
awk -F[*~] -v var="$input" '
    BEGIN{ split(var, a, "*"); a[2]++}
```

(**note:** `-F[*~]` sets your field-separators to either `'*'` or `'~'`)

Your array `a` now holds `N4` as the first element and `2` as the second element (after `1` in `a[2]` was incremented with `a[2]++`). You can then use the array elements to match the record beginning with `N4`. Now you simply need to match the records that begins with `a[1]` output the desired field, `a[2]`, which you can do simply by:

```
    $1 == a[1] {print $a[2]}
```

Putting it altogether you would do:

```
awk -F[*~] -v var="$input" '
    BEGIN{ split(var, a, "*"); a[2]++} 
    $1 == a[1] {print $a[2]}
' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

You can test just by setting the variable in your shell and then copy/middle-mouse-paste the `awk` command on the command line.

With the input as `N4*1`:

```
$ input='N4*1*'
$ awk -F[*~] -v var="$input" '
>     BEGIN{ split(var, a, "*"); a[2]++}
>     $1 == a[1] {print $a[2]}
> ' file
WALTER
```

For the second field:

```
$ input='N4*2*'
$ awk -F[*~] -v var="$input" '
>     BEGIN{ split(var, a, "*"); a[2]++}
>     $1 == a[1] {print $a[2]}
> ' file
WHITE
```

---

**Passing Separate `identifier` And `position`**

Per your edit where the user passes a separate `identifier` variable and `position` variable, you can save having to split the original variable into an array. Here you just declare an additional variable, which eliminates the need for the `BEGIN` section of the script. For example:

```
awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" '
```

Above the two shell variables have been stored as the `awk` variables `id` and `pos`, respectively. Then it is the same idea, locate the record and output the appropriate field (note: I added a check on the `position` to ensure that field is present), e.g.

```
    $1 == id { if(++pos < NF) 
        print $pos; 
    else 
        print "invalid position"
```

Above if the 1st field `$1` matches the `id`, then check that the incremented position is less than the number of fields `NF` (noting the `++` is applied as a side-effect after the evaluation making `< NF` proper instead of `<= NF`). If the file exists, print it with `print $pos` (the `'$'` being the `awk` field designator, not a variable dereference like with your shell variable) So if the user provided `position=1`, `$pos` in the script is printing the 2nd field, i.e. `$2`. If the `position` exceeds the `NF`, then the error `"invalid position"` is displayed.

The complete script would be:

```
awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" '
    $1 == id { if(++pos < NF) 
        print $pos; 
    else 
        print "invalid position" 
}' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ identifier=N4
$ position=1
$ awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" '
>     $1 == id { if(++pos < NF)
>         print $pos;
>     else
>         print "invalid position"
> }' file
WALTER
```

With `position=2`:

```
$ position=2
$ awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" '
>     $1 == id { if(++pos < NF)
>         print $pos;
>     else
>         print "invalid position"
> }' file
WHITE
```

A check on the error reporting:

```
$ position=3
$ awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" '
>     $1 == id { if(++pos < NF)
>         print $pos;
>     else
>         print "invalid position"
> }' file
invalid position
```

---

**Per-Edit -- Multiple Identifiers Per-Line**

If you have multiple identifiers per-line and you want to use to position relative to each identifier, you can loop over each of the fields and compare if the field equals the `identifier` and if so, then test if there is a field that would satisfy a position offset from the identifier -- if so print the field as position from the identifier, otherwise handle the error.

You can do that with the following:

```
awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" '
    id { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
        if ($i == id) { 
            if (i+pos <= NF)
                print $(i+pos)
            else
                print "invalid position"
        }
    }
' file
```

**New Example Input File**

```
$ cat file
N4*WALTER*WHITE~DMG*D8*19630625~N4*CORA*PA*15108~
```

**Example Use/Output**

With `position=1`:

```
$ awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" '
>     id { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
>         if ($i == id) {
>             if (i+pos <= NF)
>                 print $(i+pos)
>             else
>                 print "invalid position"
>         }
>     }
> ' file
WALTER
CORA
```

With `position=2`:

```
$ awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" '
>     id { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
>         if ($i == id) {
>             if (i+pos <= NF)
>                 print $(i+pos)
>             else
>                 print "invalid position"
>         }
>     }
> ' file
WHITE
PA
```

(it helps to have the actual data in the original question)

Comment: Sure, that makes it easier for the `awk` above.  I'll add an example.

Comment: thanks much, but my data in text.file may sometimes look different. I updated to the post.  So the solution you given is not working.

Comment: thanks much, but my data in text.file may sometimes look different. I updated to the post.  So the solution you given is not working. that is the reason i want to first take the segment into a variable then display the content based on input.    grep -P -o '(?<=$identifier).*?(?=~)'        this grep will give the lines matching with N4 until ~ then how to use awk and input to display the element with position asked in input ?

Comment: Oh, so now there may be 2 identifiers per-line. That too is doable, just quite different from the original post. Let me look at it.

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation. This works Perfect. Could you please correct my understanding ? awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position"  ---- In awk options you have given -F [*~]  which tells the input record field separators either by * or ~.   then you declared two variables $identifier and $position within awk.  then selection criteria started between `  `  .  you defined id {  }  .. what we call this ?     what is the statement that actually takes all N4*XXX~ stings ?

Comment: how can i avoid false positives ?  assume every identifier starts with ~ and end with ~.   there is N4 in PER identifier which i don't want to take. If i give input as ~N4*1* , i thought the problem will be solved. But it is not working.

Comment: The two awk variables `id` and `pos` just take your shell variables `identifier` and `position`. When you see `id {....}` at the beginning of the rule, it says match `id` in the current line and then do `{...}` what is in the braces. You can match with either a string (like `id`) or a regular expression with `/someregex/ {...}` (or just match against a particular file, e.g. `$1 == id {...}`) To not match the first `~N4`, simply loop `for (i=2; i<=NF; i++)` to skip checking the 1st field.

Comment: @ David C Rankin:  I mean i changed $identifier to ~N4 instead of N4.  then the script is not working. why ?

Comment: Well, of course not, because `~N4` will only match at the beginning, but since we have separators of `'*'` and `'~'` all `'~'` will be removed and it can never match. If you are going to change something that effects the separators -- you have to change the separators too `:)`

Comment: Oh ok. In this scenario, is there a way to avoid false positives ? I don't want to get PINK from the data as that N4 is in PER Segment.   What i am thinking is before even running awk loop, i will update the source file search string not equal to ~N4 and update remaining N4 with some dummy like "ACBCFEIDKE".  once the awk loop complete then i will update back ACBGFEIDKE with N4 ? Is this good practice in linux ? I believe this will work perfectly.

Comment: I tried below and it is working. this will avoid false positives.  step1: rename actual identifiers-->
 sed -i "s/[~]$identifier/TEMPUPD1/g" file.txt

step2: rename false positives (remaining N4) -->
 sed -i "s/$identifier/TEMPUPD2/g" file.txt

step3: revert back actual identifiers -->
 sed -i "s/TEMPUPD1/~$identifier/g"

step4: run awk loop 

step5: revert back false positives -->
sed -i "s/TEMPUPD2/$identifier/g" file.txt

Comment: I am trying to update the output that was displayed using awk. I tried below but it is not working.    awk -F[*~] -v id="$identifier" -v pos="$position" '
     { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)
          if ($i == id) {
                        if (i+pos <= NF)
                        print $(i+pos)
                        else
                        print "invalid position"
                        } {$(i+pos)="NEWDATA"}
       }' file.txt

Comment: `print $(i+pos)` prints the field `i + pos`, `{$(i+pos)="NEWDATA"} ` can be beyond the end of `NF` as it isn't below the check `if (i+pos <= NF)`. At this point, if you are having problems with some aspect of your changed code, it is better to ask another question and include the output you are getting. That helps everyone figure out what and why it isn't working. Asking new questions in comments makes it very hard to fully answer.

Comment: @ David C. Rankin: Sorry. Will ask this as new question.

Comment: just asked as new question "Update data in source file with random data from another file"